# What is going on with this preg_replace?

Tags: php

What is going on with the \w character type? At the moment it outputs an array called $replace that has all the name except only the first letter of each first name. I don't really understand what its doing to get to this point. \w is any word character but that doesn't help me.

```
<?php

$rappers = array('Drake Themotto', 'Tom Ford', 'Lil Wayne');

$replace = preg_replace('/(\w)\w* (\w)/', '\1 \2', $rappers);

print_r($replace);

?>
```

Comment: We don't have your code, so we can't really identify your problem.

Comment: Lil Wayne must be the issue. /s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From left to right your regex contains:

1. A group with one word character
2. Zero or more word characters
3. A space
4. A group with one word character

For "Drake Themotto" this means:

1. The first group \1 will be "D"
2. The following word characters "rake" match but will not be stored
3. The space will not be stored
4. The second group \2 will be "T"

For the replacement this means that the matching part of your string is "Drake T". This matching string will be replaced by "\1 \2" which is "D T" in this case.

After that, there are some other characters "hemotto". You did not mention them in your regex, but since it does not contain a $ to mark the end of the string (in this case the regex would not match) or another \w* to match (= in this case: to remove) the other characters of the string, this rest simply will be ignored. Because you just "replace" something, "ignored" means that nothing will be replaced here and it will be appended to the result.

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot and made perfect sense!